# Why is Unity 2D Alpha-Blurring my pixel sprite?

Tags: unity, 2d

So I have just brought in a place holder block for the ground in unity 2D, and it's 16 by 16 pixel image, and for some reason unity is automatically blurring the image. So I was wondering if there was any way to stop unity from automatically blurring the image. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to stop the image form being blurred. Also sorry if this is, just something that is incredibly simple to fix, I just started using unity 2D instead of 3D so it's different for me.

Thanks, Nova

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default sprite filter mode in Unity is set to Bilinear.

If you change it to Point, it will retain the pixel crisp.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FilterMode.html